# If statement to run loop on first sheet in VBA

Tags: excel, for-loop, if-statement, reference, vba

Need help with creating an If-Statement within a for loop, to run the loop specifically on the first sheet, then "else" on the rest of the sheets. Is there a way to reference the first sheet? For example, if the sheet==sheet(1)...then.., else do...

I'm new to VBA, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
If theSheet Is Sheets(1) Then
```

or

```
If theSheet.Index = 1 Then
```